# object detection using numpy array of pixels

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, raspberry-pi

Hey guys so for a python project I'm using a pi camera to continuously take pictures while a conveyor belt is running underneath it with objects coming in. I'm trying to write a program that will detect when the entirety of an object is underneath the camera by running a loop for each frame/image that compares the top row of pixels with the bottom  to see if there's any difference. If there is, we then enter our case-specific for loop to look to see if the top row and bottom row of pixels are now the same. If they are then we know that the object has fully entered the frame of the camera (we assume the object will never be larger than the frame of the picture)

So my question is if there's a more accurate way for me to do this pixel detection. Should I consider taking the average pixel value of the top and bottom rows and then applying some sort of acceptable range of difference since a the lighting might not be consistent throughout the whole image? such as: if (topRowAvg < 1.1* bottomRowAvg and topRowAvg > .9* bottomRowAvg):?

I'm open to all ears. Code below

```
def objectDetection()
    objectDetected = false
    # allow the camera to warmup
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # capture frames from the camera
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
     if(objectDetected == true):
        for x in range(width)
            if(np.all(image[x,0]) == np.all(image[x,height])):
                    #unimportant  line of code to resolve
                    return

        for x in range((width-1)):
            if(np.all(image[x,0]) > np.all(image[x,height])):
            objectDetected = true
```

Comment: Did you try using a picture of the empty conveyor belt as a reference? As long as the conveyor belt is uniform enough in color (so its appearance doesn't change as it moves under the camera) and as long as your illumination is constant, then this gives you a very simple way of detecting objects on your conveyor belt.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, the idea is that the conveyor belt is going to be uniform in color. Although would it matter if I change the picture to gray scale or leave it as color

Comment: If your objects contrast well enough with the conveyor belt in gray scale, then convert to gray scale. If the luminance is similar, and you need color to distinguish them, don't convert.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, for the response. This is my first time posting on here so you've already made this a positive experience.

Comment: I know it's your first time. I can also tell you didn't take the [tour] because you don't have a bronze badge next to your name! ;) Welcome to SO!